# align the content of a div header horizontally boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align the content of a div header horizontally using bootsrap but it is not working as the the two content are pulled to the right. This is my attempt

```
<div class = "page-header">
   <img class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4" class="img-responsive" src="/resources/images/header.png">
    <hgroup class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
  <h1 style="color: black;">XXXX</h1>
  <h3 style="color:black;">XX</h3>
</hgroup>
 </div>
```

Please how can align the image and the hgroup horizontally thesame

Answer (score 0):

try this way class name like `col-md-pull-4` to `col-md-pull-8` & `col-md-push-4` to `col-md-push-8`

```
<div class="page-header row">
    <img class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 img-responsive" src="/resources/images/header.png">
    <hgroup class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
        <h1 style="color: black;">XXXX</h1>
        <h3 style="color:black;">XX</h3>
    </hgroup>
</div>
```

Comment: the two contents dissappeared

Comment: you use 2time class attribute "class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4" class="img-responsive"

Comment: I am using one and it was not horizontally aligned

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class = "page-header">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="/resources/images/header.png">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <hgroup>
          <h1 style="color: black;">XXXX</h1>
          <h3 style="color:black;">XX</h3>
       </hgroup>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the two where pushed to the left

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/resources/images/header.png">
  </div>
  <hgroup class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
    <h1 style="color: black;">XXXX</h1>
    <h3 style="color:black;">XX</h3>
  </hgroup>
</div>
```